# Aligning a Button with a Select Box (HTML Forms)

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am trying to create a Search panel on a page, consisting of three select boxes (dropdowns) and a button. however I am unable to get them to line-up. This must have been doen thousands of times before yet it is giving me so much grief.

In an effort to simplify it and understand what is going on, I created the following minimalist page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" name="search1" id="search1">
                <td bgcolor="#FF0000">
                    <select class="searchbox" name="type" style="width:140px">
                        <option value="">choose a style.....</option>
                        <option value="beach">Beach</option>
                        <option value="city">City</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td bgcolor="#FF0000">
                    <input type="image" name="submit" id="submit" alt="submit" src="../images/transparent.png" width="35px" height="30px" style="background-color:#00C">
                </td>
            </form>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

The result looks like this in Firefox,

this in Chrome,

this in IE9,

and this in IE9 Compatibiity View.

Sorry, I'm not allowed to post images as I'm a newbie, but take it from me, they're all different. I haven't even dared to look at it in older versions of IE!

How can I get the select box to vertically align centrally with the button in all browsers? I must be missing something obvious: it's not rocket surgery!

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/LI9vf.gif
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcCKN.gif
3. https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHAkP.gif
4. https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUXkl.gif

Comment: rocket surgery? that's new...

Answer (score 0):

You need to play with `line-height` and `vertical-align`...
And theres no real need for a table there, well at least not in the simplified example you posted:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="" method="post" name="search1" id="search1">
<div style="background-color:red;padding:0;height:30px;line-height:30px;">
    <select class="searchbox" name="type" style="width:140px">
       <option value="">choose a style.....</option>
       <option value="beach">Beach</option>
       <option value="city">City</option>
    </select>
    <input type="image" name="submit" id="submit" alt="submit" src="../images/transparent.png" style="background-color:#00C;margin:0;padding:0;width:35px;height:30px;vertical-align:bottom;">
</div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's interesting. I'll go away and try that. I think I do need the table in the real version, which is somewhat more complex than the simplified version I was playing with here.